# Как проверить Basic Authorization в python spyne?

Tags: python, python-3.x, аутентификация, авторизация

Как используя spyne в python реализовать базовую (Basic) аутентификацию входящего сообщения?

Это вообще возможно?

Пробовал считать заголовки ctx.transport.headers - заголовок 'Authorization' отсутствует.

Использую версии spyne 2.13.16, python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Пока я еще не знаю, как это сделать в spyne, но решил эту проблему добавлением еще одного пакета wsgi-basic-auth c помощью класса BasicAuth:

```
from spyne import Application
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from wsgi_basic_auth import BasicAuth

application = Application([...], name='...', tns='...', in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

basic_application = BasicAuth(wsgi_application, users={'LOGIN': 'PASSWORD'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', PORT, basic_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```